# Different background color animation for each item.hover()

Tags: jquery, jquery-color

I'm setting up a new website and want to implement some css animations for the menu via jQuery.

I'm using WordPress for this and the theme I've installed has a mega menu-style plugin. The submenu of each menu link has a different background color. The submenus fade in on mouse hover.

What I want to do is have the menu bar change background color simultaneously with the fade in animation of the submenu. So the duration etc. should match perfectly.

As the submenu of each link has a different background color, I would like the background color of the menu bar to match the background of the currently active submenu. It would have start with something like menulink.hover() I imagine.

An important point: The submenus kind of fade into each other if you hover different menu links by turns. So obviously I would like the background color of the menu bar to also fade into each other as different menu links are hovered.

Disclaimer: I have little to none jQuery/JS experience. :)

I tried:

1. Toggling between classes for each menu link and then using CSS to set different background colors, transitions
2. item.css (didn't work because I couldn't set the duration)
3. item.animate (the background color change just doesn't match, plus the colors don't fade into each other; i.e. if you hover 'menu link 1' and then 'menu link 2', the background color goes slightly white between the two background color changes, whereas the submenus stay at 100% opacity and fade smoothly into each other)

```
var jnews_menu = [$('#menu-item-3646'),$('#menu-item-3647'),$('#menu-item-3648'),$('#menu-item-4123')];

  //this is the variable for menu bar
  var jnews_menubar = $('.jeg_navbar');
  var jnews_nav_border = $('.jeg_nav_row');

  jnews_menu.forEach(myFunction);

  function myFunction(item, index) {
    item.hover(function(){
      switch(index) {
        case 0:
          jnews_menubar.animate({backgroundColor: "#ff3996"}, 350 );
          jnews_nav_border.animate({borderBottomColor: "transparent"}, 350) ;
          break;
        case 1:
          jnews_menubar.animate({backgroundColor: "#ff9b39"}, 350 );
          jnews_nav_border.animate({borderBottomColor: "transparent"}, 350 );
          break;
        case 2:
          jnews_menubar.animate({backgroundColor: "#9ce4ff"}, 350 );
          jnews_nav_border.animate({borderBottomColor: "transparent"}, 350) ;
          break;
        case 3:
          jnews_menubar.animate({backgroundColor: "#cd9cff"}, 350);
          jnews_nav_border.animate({borderBottomColor: "transparent"}, 350 );
          break;

      }
    }, function(){
          jnews_menubar.animate({backgroundColor: "transparent"}, 350 );
          jnews_nav_border.animate({borderBottomColor: "#4ac3ef"}, 350 );
    });
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `jnews_menu` ? You should use the right variable names

Comment: Sorry, it seems I didn't copy and paste all the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

This  is due to animation buildups. You're stacking animations on each other. instead use `.stop()` to clear the animation queue before starting another animate:

```
.stop().animate(
```

or like this example, which uses CSS for the `transition`:

```js
var $navbar = $('.Navbar');
var $row = $navbar.find('.Navbar-row');

$row.css('backgroundColor', function() {
  return $(this).data('bg'); // Set each element background
}).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $navbar.css({backgroundColor: $(this).data('bg')});
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $navbar.css({backgroundColor: $navbar.data('bg')});
  }
});
```

```css
.Navbar {
  background:#4ac3ef;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
.Navbar-row {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Navbar" data-bg="#4ac3ef">
  <div class="Navbar-row" data-bg="#ff3996">Hover me</div>
  <div class="Navbar-row" data-bg="#ff9b39">Hover me</div>
  <div class="Navbar-row" data-bg="#9ce4ff">Hover me</div>
  <div class="Navbar-row" data-bg="#cd9cff">Hover me</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm no expert and have very little jQuery/Javascript knowledge... Would you be able to explain what you've done in more detail? The structure of my menu is different so the code would need to be adjusted as well (i.e. it's actually a container inside the submenu that has the background color). Also, I cannot set <pre>data-bg</pre> to any of the menu links, all the styling is done via css. Sorry for any confusion and many thanks, you've been super helpful :)